# How to format internal Java names?

Tags: java

I'm parsing a report that returns Java method signatures as something like:

```
method(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;ZI)V
```

What's the best way to convert this back into something that's more human-readable? For example, the above should be something like:

```
void method(String, String, boolean, int)
```

Comment: What would be the desired output for the example you provided?

Comment: Presumably you want something that reads like a method signature back, with `a`, `b`, `c` etc. substituted in as parameter names?

Comment: What?  That isn't "human readable"?  I understand it perfectly!

Comment: @HotLicks - perhaps that says more about you than the format :-)

Comment: @HotLicks, not the qualification 'more' before 'human-readable' ;-)

Comment: @A.R.S., I've edited the question to include the desired output. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Actually, it should be `...(String, String[], boolean, int)`

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of examples of code that does this:

- http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/ba/SignatureConverter.html
- http://attrib4j.sourceforge.net/apidocs/attrib4j/bcel/DescriptorUtil.html

If all else fails, you copy the code from one or other of these places.

A couple of things to note:

- You cannot recover meaningful variable names for a signature (obviously ...)
- If the methods are generic, this is not indicated in the signature.  The signature information is for the raw (erased) method type.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to implement their own (as I'll be doing in Scala if only to get some practice with its parsing capabilities), from http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q7 describes the mangling:

- Primitive representations:

  - 'V' - void
  - 'Z' - boolean
  - 'C' - char
  - 'B' - byte
  - 'S' - short
  - 'I' - int
  - 'F' - float
  - 'J' - long
  - 'D' - double
- Class representations:

  - L*class*;
  - Ljava/io/ObjectOutput;
  - Ljava/lang/String;

The only thing it's missing are arrays which seem to be prefixed with '[' (eg [Z), perhaps one per dimension.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

class JavaSignatureParser extends RegexParsers {
  def signature: Parser[String] = methodName ~ "(" ~ parameters ~ ")" ~ result ^^ {
    case m ~ "(" ~ p ~ ")" ~ r => r + " " + m + "(" + p + ")"
  }
  def methodName: Parser[String] = regularName ~ opt(specialName) ^^ {
    case m ~ None => m
    case c ~ Some(s) => c + s
  }
  def regularName: Parser[String] = """[A-Z0-9a-z_.$]+""".r
  def specialName: Parser[String] = "&lt;" ~> initializer <~ "&gt;" ^^ ("<" + _ + ">")
  def initializer: Parser[String] = "init" | "clinit"
  def result: Parser[String] = void | nonVoid
  def parameters: Parser[String] = rep(nonVoid) ^^ {
    case Nil => ""
    case p => p.reduceLeft(_ + ", " + _)
  }
  def nonVoid: Parser[String] = primitive | reference | array
  def primitive: Parser[String] = boolean | char | byte | short | int | float | long | double
  def void: Parser[String] = "V" ^^ (_ => "void")
  def boolean: Parser[String] = "Z" ^^ (_ => "boolean")
  def char: Parser[String] = "C" ^^ (_ => "char")
  def byte: Parser[String] = "B" ^^ (_ => "byte")
  def short: Parser[String] = "S" ^^ (_ => "short")
  def int: Parser[String] = "I" ^^ (_ => "int")
  def float: Parser[String] = "F" ^^ (_ => "float")
  def long: Parser[String] = "J" ^^ (_ => "long")
  def double: Parser[String] = "D" ^^ (_ => "double")
  def reference: Parser[String] = "L" ~> """[^;]+""".r <~ ";" ^^ { path =>
    val JavaName = """^java\..*\.([^.]+)""".r
    val fqcn = (path.replaceAll("/", "."))

    fqcn match {
      case JavaName(simpleName) => simpleName
      case qualifiedName => qualifiedName
    }
  }
  def array: Parser[String] = "[" ~> nonVoid ^^ (_ + "[]")
}
```